# How difficult is it to add vibration feedback to a open-source driving game?

Tags: c++, open-source, force-feedback

I'm looking to use [SuperTuxKart](http://supertuxkart.sourceforge.net/) as a basis for a PhD research project. A key requirement for the game is to provide vibration feedback through the controller (obviously dependant on the controller itself).  I don't believe that the game currently includes this feature and I'm trying to get a feel for how big a challenge it would be to add.

My background is as a J2EE and PHP developer/architect, so I don't know C++ as such, but am prepared to give it a crack if there are resources and guides to assist, and it's not a herculean task.

Alternatively, if you know of any open source games that do include vibration feedback, please feel free to let me know!  Preferably the game would be of the style that the player had to navigate a character (or character's vehicle) over a repeatable course/map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears SuperTuxKart is built using [Irrlicht](http://www.irrlicht3d.org/), so the question is in that context. [This wiki page](http://www.irrlicht3d.org/wiki/index.php?n=Main.IntegratingOISWithIrrlicht) shows how to replace Irrlicht's internal input library with [OIS](http://www.wreckedgames.com/) which apparently supports force feedback.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Well as you said this is mostly dependant on the device you'll be using. My answer will only be theoretical. 
The most important to make things simple is to be sure that the controller has a public (or not) Sdk or Api that let you  bind it with your game engine.

For your second question, my first guess would be XNA which supports natively the Xbox controller. But again this depends on your choice of controller.

Answer (score -1):

Try Rigs of Rods. Great game, and it has force feedback.
http://www.rigsofrods.com

Comment: It would be better if you pointed to, say, where in the source repo the force feedback code was.